# Cannot get a angular js file in node and angular aplication

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

I try to create a simple SPA application and in html file i have errors like:  "failed to load resource: angular.js", "failed to load resource: angular-route.js", "failed to load resource: myApp.js" and similar. Like the path is wrong but is not.

This is a part of my server in Node:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var path = require("path"); 
var app = express(); 
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var bower = require('bower'); 
var userRouter = require('../app/controller/users'); 
var aplikacijaRouter = require('../app/controller/aplikacije');

var dogadjajRouter = require('../app/controller/dogadjaji');




// connection with mongodb

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pracenje_gresaka_db')

// configuration of bodyParser()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8181; 

//view of html files
app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/" + "example1.html" ));
 });

app.get('/signup', function(req, res){
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/" + "signup.html" ));
 });

 app.get('/login', function(req, res){
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/" + "login.html" ));
 });
```

This is a html example1 with paths for angular:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myApp.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>
      Example
    </h1>
    <div ng-view> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is a myApp.js but i never reach it:

```
(function(angular) {

  var helloController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello from the controller!";
    };


  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);
  app.controller('helloCon', helloController);

  app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/main',{
      templateUrl: 'primer01-entries.html',
      controller: 'helloCon'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo:'/main'
    });
  });
})(angular);
```

[**Image of error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw27K.png)
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like `../bower_components` folder is served by Express over HTTP.

Check http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I try with : app.use(express.static(__dirname  '/bower_components'));  but still not recognize angular,js. I dont know why.